# Regex for matching portions of URL

Tags: java, regex

I need help creating a regex to match specific portions of a URL using Java. Specifically the protocol, the hostname, and the port.

For example, if I have a URL `http://hq.dev.test.domain:8080/ip/CreateRegex` and
I would like to pull out the following:

```
[Protocol]=http
[Hostname]=hq.dev.test.domain
[Port]=8080
```

Here is what I currently have which works only for the Protocol. I'll take any updates on this regex as well.

```
var getProtocol= ^((http)?:\\/\\/).*\\w*(CreateRegex)$
```

Comment: are these keywords coming as a multi line or everything is in one line?

Comment: is this a homework? If not java's own URL class has API to protocol, host and port.

Comment: Is this Java or Javascript? Your use of `var` makes me think it's the latter.

Comment: var is supported now in Java 10 onwards

Comment: Tom, the keywords are coming from a web.config file and I'm using Xpath to read the values and java to output them into an in to use for a Inno script installer.
Jayan, no this is not HW.
gla3der I started off using Javascript but went to Java.  The java.net.URL class for parsing was the best option

Comment: In that case my edit probably should not have been approved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [`java.net.URL`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/net/URL.html) class for parsing

```
URL url = new URL("https://google.com:443/search");
System.out.println(url.getProtocol()); // https
System.out.println(url.getHost()); // google.com
System.out.println(url.getPort()); // 443
```

Answer (score 0):

Is there any particular reason to use regex for your case? If not you should use `URL` to parse the string.

```
URL url = new URL("http://hq.dev.test.domain:8080/ip/CreateRegex");
System.out.println("[Protocol]=" + url.getProtocol());
System.out.println("[Hostname]=" + url.getHost());
System.out.println("[Port]=" + url.getPort());
```

For the sake of completeness though here how you'd go about it with regex :

```
Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("^(\\w+)://([^:/]*)(?::(\\d+))?.*");
Matcher regexMatcher = regex.matcher("http://hq.dev.test.domain:8080/ip/CreateRegex");
if (regexMatcher.find()) {
    System.out.println("[Protocol]=" + regexMatcher.group(1));
    System.out.println("[Hostname]=" + regexMatcher.group(2));
    System.out.println("[Port]=" + regexMatcher.group(3));
}
```